# Flutter - losing state when pressing back button to android home screen

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I have an issue with flutter. I have managed to implement a basic navigation system that keeps state when you do either of the following:

- switch between tabs
- press the android home button and re-open the app (either by clicking on the app again or using the list of active app button (the little square at the bottom))

But if I press the back button - going back to the android homescreen I completely lose state. I have re-implemented some code to randomly generate a number and display it on the app - this way I know if I'm getting the same widget or a new one has been built.

Why do I need this? (if you're interested)
I'm creating an audio app and when I click play song, it plays. but when I click back to the home screen and let it play in the background -> then open the app again, I can play it again and have it playing twice!

Main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'BottomNavigationBarController.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Login',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BottomNavigationBarController(),
    );
  }
}
```

Bottom navigation tab (BottomNavigationBarController):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'PlaceholderWidget.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarController extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomNavigationBarController({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarController createState() => _BottomNavigationBarController();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarController extends State<BottomNavigationBarController>{

  int _selectedPage = 0;
  List<Widget> pageList = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageList.add(PlaceholderWidget());
    pageList.add(PlaceholderWidget());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedPage,
        children: pageList,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.phone_android),
            title: Text('First Page'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.phone_android),
            title: Text('Second Page'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPage = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Random number widget (PlaceholderWidget):

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlaceholderWidget extends StatefulWidget  {


  PlaceholderWidget({Key key, this.color}) : super(key: key);
  final Color color;
  @override
  _PlaceholderWidget createState() => _PlaceholderWidget();
}

class _PlaceholderWidget extends State<PlaceholderWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      color: widget.color,
      child: Text(random_num().toString()),
    );
  }

  int random_num(){
    Random  random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
    return randomNumber;
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Navigator pop deletes the widget not entirely sure. But If you want to save the current state just use navigator push don't pop. Also use named routes this will help you greatly.

Comment: Could you explain how I use navigator push - but don't pop? I will look into named routes. Thank you for your answer

Comment: just don't call your navigator.pop(context). I also agree try to learn state management its an essential thing to learn for becoming a pro~ <3

Answer (score 0):

Use Provider to pass state and keep a global store.

If your app will need to scale, now is a good time to start with MobX/BLoC/Redux/InheritedWidget.. etc.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean but I will look into it thank you :)

Comment: @RMRiver those are all libraries you can include in you project that help with those issues.